# ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found

Tags: gcc, cmake, libstdc++

I am getting the error:

```
(genslm) smrutip@dgx1:~/smruti_project/pyro-cov$ make analyze 
python scripts/mutrans.py --vary-holdout Traceback (most recent call last): File "/raid/home/smrutip/smruti_project/pyro-cov/scripts/mutrans.py", line 16, in from pyrocov import mutrans, pangolin, sarscov2 File "/raid/home/smrutip/smruti_project/pyro-cov/pyrocov/mutrans.py", line 37, in import pyrocov.geo File "/raid/home/smrutip/smruti_project/pyro-cov/pyrocov/geo.py", line 12, in import pandas as pd File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/init.py", line 48, in from pandas.core.api import ( File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 47, in from pandas.core.groupby import ( File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/init.py", line 1, in from pandas.core.groupby.generic import ( File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 77, in from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 182, in from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 179, in from pandas.core.window import ( File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/init.py", line 1, in from pandas.core.window.ewm import ( File "/raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/ewm.py", line 11, in import pandas._libs.window.aggregations as window_aggregations 
ImportError: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /raid/home/smrutip/anaconda3/envs/genslm/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window/aggregations.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so) make: *** [Makefile:63: analyze] Error 1
```

but couldnt solve it using any of the solutions. I am not supposed to use sudo command due to permission issues. Can anyone tell me how to solve it using conda?

I am expecting this "make analyze" should work and give results

Comment: Please include an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: similar error. Neither solution posted to date works.

Answer (score 2):

simple and almsot silly solution. I got this error when importing `pandas`. Simply uninstall and reinstall `pandas` solved the issue. The solution posted above didn't fix that for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this error occurred due to different `gcc` and `g++` versions. Please check your versions via the following:

```cpp
gcc --version
g++ --version
```

Updating and having the same `gcc` and `g++` versions solved this issue. To install those in your conda environment, use the following command:
To install gcc:

```cpp
conda install -c conda-forge gcc
```

To install g++:

```
conda install -c conda-forge gxx
```

I hope this helps you. Thanks!

Comment: Still I am getting the same error
strings /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

Comment: Could you post the complete error? This is not the error. This is the output of all the `GLIBCXX` files available in your system.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed pandas using conda. Here is what worked for me.

Uninstall pandas via conda

```
conda uninstall pandas
```

Install pandas using pip

```
pip install pandas
```